# The Replace method not working ,C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a phone number converter code with C# ,struggling with replacing any alphabetic character to its corresponding number on the phone keys.In the code down here ,the variable result already has a 10 characters ,wich is a mix of numbers and letters.As you see in the code ,I'm trying to use the Replace method through out the switch case,but it gives me wrong results .Any ideas ?Thanks.
Sorry I forgot to mention that Arrays are not allowed to be used in this project,only conditions and repeatition.Ah ,and it's console C#.

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {

            switch (buffer)
            {

                case "A":
                case "B":
                case "C": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "2");
                    break;
                case "D":
                case "E":
                case "F": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "3");
                    break;

                case "G":
                case "H":
                case "I": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "4");
                    break;



                case "J":
                case "K":
                case "L": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "5");
                    break;


                case "M":
                case "N":
                case "O": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "6");
                    break;

                case "P":
                case "Q":
                case "R":
                case "S": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "7");
                    break;

                case "T":
                case "U":
                case "V": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "8");
                    break;


                case "W":
                case "X":
                case "Y":
                case "Z": myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "9");
                    break;

            }


            Console.WriteLine("({0})-{1}-{2}", myNumber.Substring(0, 3), myNumber.Substring(3, 3), myNumber.Substring(6, 4));
```

Comment: Where did `buffer` come from? I feel that you're missing a line of code before the `switch` that assigns a value to `buffer`.

Comment: What is 'buffer'? Shouldn't it be `result.Chars[i]`?

Comment: How the heck is substring from 6 to 4 not blowing up??

Comment: @AMR It's not `from, to`, it's `from, length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following rewrite...

```
    string result = "1800CALLME";
    string myNumber = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) 
    {
    string buffer = result[i].ToString(); 
    switch (buffer)
    {

        case "A":
        case "B":
        case "C": myNumber += "2";
            break;
        case "D":
        case "E":
        case "F": myNumber += "3";
            break;

        case "G":
        case "H":
        case "I": myNumber += "4";
            break;

        case "J":
        case "K":
        case "L": myNumber += "5";
            break;

        case "M":
        case "N":
        case "O": myNumber += "6";
            break;

        case "P":
        case "Q":
        case "R":
        case "S": myNumber += "7";
            break;

        case "T":
        case "U":
        case "V": myNumber += "8";
            break;


        case "W":
        case "X":
        case "Y":
        case "Z": myNumber += "9";
            break;

    }


    Console.WriteLine("({0})-{1}-{2}", myNumber.Substring(0, 3), myNumber.Substring(3, 3), myNumber.Substring(6, 4));
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Can I replace the result[i] with result ?Arrays are not allowed to be used in my project.

Comment: You could the do the following if you like...string buffer = result.Substring(i, 1);

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning `Replace` method result to `myNumber`, but in next loop iteration you're taking `result` as `Replace` parameter again. It can't work.

How about that:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> PhoneReplacements =
    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "A", "1" }, { "B", "1" }, { "C", "1" },
        { "D", "2" }, { "E", "2" }, { "F", "2" },
        { "G", "3" }, { "H", "3" }, { "I", "3" }
        // (...)
    };

private static string GetPhoneNumber(string number)
{
    foreach(var r in PhoneReplacements)
    {
        number = number.Replace(r.Key, r.Value);
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Looks good ,but unfortunatley for this project I'm not allowed to work with arrays or Dictionary ,just conditions and repetition.

Answer (score 1):

`String` are immutable. When you do

```
result.Replace(buffer, "9");
```

result does not change.

So, you are only using the replacement of the last iteration, not the combination of all the replacements that your code has done. That is what you are assigning to your code.

Instead of

```
myNumber = result.Replace(buffer, "9");
```

do

```
result = result.Replace(buffer, "9");
```

or even, if you wish

```
myNumber = result = result.Replace(buffer, "9");
```

Comment: And yes, that assumes that "buffer" is the digit/letter currently being evaluated. If it is not, that is the first error you should correct.

Comment: Still doesn't give me the correct result.It prints the phine number with the letters with out replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

Do remember to use StringBuilder when building strings, especialy when building strings in iterations.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Char, Byte> mappings = new Dictionary<Char, Byte>() {
    { 'A', 2 }, { 'B', 2 }, { 'C', 2 },
    { 'D', 3 }, { 'E', 3 }, { 'F', 3 },
    { 'G', 4 }, { 'H', 4 }, { 'I', 4 },
    { 'J', 5 }, { 'K', 5 }, { 'L', 5 },
    { 'M', 6 }, { 'N', 6 }, { 'O', 6 },
    { 'P', 7 }, { 'Q', 7 }, { 'R', 7 }, { 'S', 7 },
    { 'T', 8 }, { 'U', 8 }, { 'V', 8 },
    { 'W', 9 }, { 'X', 9 }, { 'Y', 9 }, { 'Z', 9},
    { ' ', 0 }
};

private static string StringToKeystrokes(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (mappings.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            sb.Append(mappings[c]);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Using the code.

```
string s = "ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQRS TUV WXYZ";
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(StringToKeystrokes(s));
```